# How to migrate all analytics data from old google analytics to GA4?

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, analytics

I need to migrate all my data from google analytics to google analytics 4. but after following the instruction, my historical data is not migrated. I need my analytical data from the beginning of time until now. here's the sample.

[image: Data on Google Analytics 4]

[image: Data from old Google Analytics]

I want my data from old google analytics to be migrated to GA4

Answer (score 1):

You cannot migrate your old Universal Analytics data to GA4, they are two different systems working with two different logics.